# Sum of the number of factors of natural numbers equality

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I have come upon the problem of proving an equality of the divisor function

How can you prove that the the expressions for the summatory divisor function are the same; $ \sum_{m=1}^n d(m) = \sum_{m=1}^n \lfloor \frac{n}{m} \rfloor $. The explanation I find in the Wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function) is not clear enough for me, and I am trying to see if it is possible to prove it on simpler terms and without referring to the other expressions shown there.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is something missing --- the second sum is empty.

Comment: Thank you for noticing, fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**.  I'm beginning with my second solution because I think it's better than my first.   But I'm leaving the first too as some people have already upvoted it.

So, we count in two ways the number of pairs $(j,k)$ of positive integers such that $jk\le n$.  First, the number of pairs with $jk=m$ is just $d(m)$, so the total number of pairs is
$$\sum_ {m=1}^n d(m)\ .$$
On the other hand, the number of pairs with a given value of $j$ is $n/j$ rounded down, and so the total is
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\Bigl  \lfloor \frac{n}{j}\Bigr \rfloor \ .$$
Therefore the two sums are equal.

---

The other solution is really the same, but with more explicit algebra.

Changing the name of the variable and writing the expression as a double sum,
$$RHS=\sum_{j=1}^n\Bigl\lfloor\frac{n}{j}\Bigr\rfloor
  =\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/j\rfloor}1\ .$$
Note that the condition on $k$, namely, $1\le k\le\lfloor n/j\rfloor$, is equivalent to $1\le jk\le n$.  So we have
$$RHS=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k:1\le jk\le n}1\ ;$$
writing $jk=m$ and changing the order of summation,
$$RHS=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{m=1}^n\sum_{k:jk=m}1
  =\sum_{m=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\left.\cases{1&if $j\mid m$\cr 0&otherwise\cr}\right\}
  =\sum_{m=1}^n d(m)$$
as claimed.